# recursive counting

Tags: c, unix, recursion, directory

I need to write a program that takes a root directory and a minimum file size from the user and then counts all files that are greater than the size the user enters in all sub directories.

For some reason my recursion only counts files that are in the current working directory and does not count those in the sub directories. Any clues on how to fix this? It is correctly counting the number of files in the working directory though.

Comment: For hilarity, put a symlink to a contaiing directory into one of the (sub-)directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify path correctly when you call the function recursively. `dentry->d_name` refers the file name only; it does not contain the directory name it is belong.

Otherwise, it will try to recurse into possibly non-existing directory. (Or,will try to recurse into same directory infinitely if there's a directory whose name is same as the parent directory).

```
char path[PATH_MAX];

....

snprintf(path, sizeof path, "%s/%s", fileName, dentry->d_name);
countFiles(path, count, size);
```